# viewWillDisappear called when tab bar item selected view controller set

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Here's the scenario:

1. Window creates a tab bar controller and adds multiple tab bar item view controllers with a `UINavigationController` as the top view.
2. `viewWillAppear` gets called on the first tab bar view.
3. The user taps a control on the first tab view that pushes a view controller on the nav stack.  `viewWillDisappear` gets called.
4. After user interaction, the view is popped off the nav stack. `viewWillAppear` is called.
5. User taps something which causes another view to be pushed on the nav stack.  `viewWillDisappear` is called.
6. User taps something which causes the code to set the selectedViewController on the tab bar controller. `viewWillDisappear` gets called AGAIN on the main view for the first tab bar item.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around this by keeping a BOOL that would tell me if I need to perform the viewWillDisappear work or not.  Ugly but it works.  I was hoping there would be a better solution or that I was doing something that was obviously wrong.